# Want to get Active Workbook and keep the variable constant

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am creating a program which copys data from the source workbook and pastes it to another. However, in the way I have currently programed it, the active workbook/worksheet is changing as I am pasting data into the following sheet.
Below is an example of how I have set the source workbook and how I am calling it.

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
     Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
End Property
Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property
```

The source book is called by...

```
Property Get col2() As Long
    col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("destBook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

Then the code is called in the following example

```
Sub PasteCI()
 Dim c As Range, cDest As Range
    
  
    Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    
    Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next paste destination. C2?
    
    If c Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        cDest.Resize(6, 1).Value = "-"       'fill placeholders
    Else
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy    'got match - copy range
        cDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to keep the source sheet constant, ie when the active workbook is set all callings to wSrc is to the initial active workbook?

Comment: You would need to not update your `wSrc` reference; one way is `if wSrc is nothing then set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Is `wsSrc = wSrc.Sheets("MBI DSCR")` what you're intending?  Trying to better understand *when* the active workbook is not needed to change, as both reference `ActiveWorkbook` and you're only looking to *lock* one with your question.

Comment: That's the job of variables. Introduce a module level variable, set it once through a setter property and return it though the get property.

Comment: Ok so If i set the wSrc it will remain constant?

Comment: I am confused as to how this is done

Comment: Where are these codes located i.e. in which modules of which workbooks? Are they in the `ActiveWorkbook`? If not, what is the ActiveWorkbook's name? Are you using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module? You are using `col` in `PasteCI` which isn't declared anywhere. Is that a typo? What is wrong with your code? Are there any error messages? Why are you using `Property Get`? Please share the answers to these questions and add any additional information to your post. Screenshots of your worksheets would do wonders so would a more detailed description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how much other "stuff" you have involved in this program, but it seems needlessly complicated. Is there a reason you're not referencing/setting these variables in the same module that's doing the data transfer? If you post an example of what the data looks like I'll try to make some optimizations to your code.

Comment: Just curious, `Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find`, where the value of col variable come from ? Or did you mean `Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col2).Find` ?